# Writing array to csv python

Tags: python-3.x, export-to-csv

I promise I looked online but can't figure out how to do this in my particular case.
I've the data in array:

```
box[0]
```

I want to write it contents to CSV file.
I am using this function to write other contents as well.

```
csv=open("newFile.csv", 'a+')
csv.write(time.strftime('%d/%m/%y')+','+time.strftime('%H:%M:%S') +','+ str(round(xnew))+','+ str(round(ynew))+','+box[0])
csv.write('\n')
csv.close()
```

In this case, it is not able to write anything but when I remove box[0] it does write and csv looks like this.

```
Date        Time        X   Y
12/09/18    16:18:19    174 86
12/09/18    16:18:20    176 87
12/09/18    16:18:21    175 87
12/09/18    16:18:22    175 87
12/09/18    16:18:23    176 87
12/09/18    16:18:25    176 87
12/09/18    16:18:26    175 87
12/09/18    16:18:27    176 87
12/09/18    16:18:28    175 87
12/09/18    16:18:29    175 87
12/09/18    16:18:30    176 87
12/09/18    16:18:31    175 87
```

Comment: You could try using the `pandas` library, converting to a DataFrame, and using the `.to_csv()` method.

Comment: Can you explain with an example please & thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this solved by changing box[0] to str(box[0]).

Small change but sometimes it takes forever to figure out.

Thanks